# Multi Object Unbound Action for updating Contained Entities in OData

Tags: rest, odata, olingo

In OData, a contained entity does not have an entity set. All operations on it should be through the parent entity. And this is true for single-object APIs.

Can we have an unbound action to update multiple such contained entities by directly providing the ID with no parent in context? Would this be according to the Odata specs?

Thanks and Regards,
Jyothi

Comment: This doesn't really have anything to do with [olingo] and is more a generic query about OData concepts

Answer (score 0):

You could do it, but as an *Unbound Function* that is technically all it is, *Unbound*, there is nothing in the specification preventing you from doing it this way but it would not be constrained to a specific resource by route. That makes the `Action` unintuitive in terms of both discovery and expectations.

The *OData* way to do this would be to bind the operation to the *Parent* Entity. If the operation affects or retrieves data across multiple entities or you really want to avoid needing to resolve the *Parent* key, then it should still be bound to the *Collection* rather than being *Unbound*.

- Reserve *Unbound* Actions for operations that are outside of the model, diagnostics  or other *esoteric* implementations that otherwise don't have a single natural place in the OData Schema.

> Having an `Action` That targets single or multiple *Contained Entities* without reference to the *Parent* is in the vicinity of being an Anti-Pattern, though I can not cite any sources that explicitly support this claim, the general reason for *Contained Entities* at all is because you *can't* directly reference the contained entity without the Parent Key, it was designed for scenarios where the Parent *Key* forms part of the *Key* for the contained item.
>
> A classic example is `Invoice` and `InvoiceLines`. If your `InvoiceLines` *Key* is a simple *Line Number* and is only unique within the `Invoice` parent, so in the Database this might be a composite key using `InvoiceId`  and `LineNumber`. In this case we can only expose this Entity as being *Contained* within a specific `Invoice` because there is no other way to uniquely reference a single `InvoiceLine` item.
>
> If your *Contained Entity* has a unique *Key* **AND** you intend on performing operations directly against these Entities without reference to the *Parent Entity* then that Entity really should be exposed as a top-level collection of it's own.